# How do I use Google Maps API to change the formatted address in a form when the marker is dragged to new location?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an input form for users to enter their location.  I have the Google Maps API autocomplete working and it displays the formatted address in the input box and then drops a pin on the map in the location. Users can then drag the marker to a new place. 
Now what I want is the formatted address in the input box to change to the new formatted address when they drag the marker, however, it is instead being replaced by the latitude coordinates- not what I want.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
   <div>
      <div id="type-selector" class="pac-controls">
         <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-all" 
            checked="checked">
         <label for="changetype-all">All</label>
         <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-establishment">
         <label for="changetype-establishment">Establishments</label>
         <input type="radio" name="type" id="changetype-address">
         <label for="changetype-address">Addresses</label>
      </div>
      <div id="pac-container">
         <input id="pac-input" type="text" 
                placeholder="Enter a location">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="infowindow-content">
   <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
   <span id="place-name" class="title"></span><br>
   <span id="place-address"></span>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
    //code below is to be able to drag and change the address
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("pac-input").value = this.getPosition().lat();


    var markerAddress = this.getPosition();

    geocoder.geocode({
        "markerAddress": markerAddress
    }, function(data, status) {

        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            var add = data[1].formatted_address; //this is the full address

            // alert(add);

            for (var i = 0; i < data[1].address_components.length; i++) {

                if (data[1].address_components[i].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") {

                    document.getElementById('pac-input').value = data[1].address_components[i].short_name;

                }
            }
        }
    });
}); //end code for draggable marker
```

Here is the JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hmathies/u4pc41j4/. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing an object to the geocoder function ( `this.getPosition()` ) you need to use `location` as the parameter rather than `markerAddress` which I'm fairly sure doesn't exist - perhaps `address` would be it?

```
google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
    var target=document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var markerAddress = this.getPosition();
    /* 
        As `markerAddress` is an object rather than a string use `location` as opposed to `address`
        - there is no `markerAddress` parameter afaik
    */
    geocoder.geocode({ 'location': markerAddress }, function( data, status ) {
        if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
            var add = data[1].formatted_address;

            for( var i = 0; i < data[1].address_components.length; i++ ) {
                if( data[1].address_components[i].types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1' ) {
                    /*
                        When the desired location is found, exit the loop!
                    */
                    target.value = data[1].address_components[i].short_name;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your response was very helpful. It isn't displaying the formatted address in the input box to the new dragged location but I have a pop up saying the new location.  Thank you for your time!